# Игнорирование строки присваивания компилятором

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto hax = 0;
  //  _    _
  // | |  | |
  // | |__| | __ ___  __
  // | |__|  / _` \ \/ /
  // | |  | | (_| |>  <
  // |_|  |_|\__,_/_/\_\
  hax = 42;
  std::cout << hax;
}
```

Почему программа печатает 0, а не 42?

Comment: Наверное из-за символа "\" перед строкой hax = 42. Он дает возможность разбить строки так, что компилятор (точнее препроцессор) будет считать их за одну.

Comment: Даже в этом самом вопросе вы можете увидеть, что `hax = 42;` покрашена серым цветом, как комментарий.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat уже после поста вопроса, а не в окне редактирования

Comment: Вопрос-стёб. Иначе зачем вставлять в вопрос комментарий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем стандарт, и в 5.2.1.2 читаем:

> Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

Т.е.

> Каждый экземпляр символа обратной косой черты (\), за которым сразу следует символ новой строки, удаляется, сращивая физические исходные строки для формирования логических исходных строк.

Все, ваша последняя строка

```
// |_|  |_|\__,_/_/\_\
```

"сростается" с `hax = 42;`, превращая ее в комментарий.

Кстати, посмотрите на *цвет* этой строки в вопросе - он такой же, как и у комментария!